# Best way to structure filesystem for website to prevent direct access to files?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, filesystems

I have the following structure for my filesystem

```
public_html
 css/
 doc/
 img/
 js/
 lib/
 *.php

private_html
 miscellaneous/
```

The document root in for my website is set in `/etc/apache2/site-available` as

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
```

Currently this allows users to direct access to files from the url like `mysite.com/css/custom.css` and `mysite.com/lib/...`

What is the best way to prevent direct access to these files?  Should I just restructure the filesystem like this:

```
public_html
 *.php

private_html
 css/
 doc/
 img/
 js/
 lib/
 miscellaneous/
```

And update the paths of the included scripts in the php files?

Comment: I don't underhand why you want to do this, or what it is that you're trying to achieve. A browser will need direct access to the files if it is to load them as part of a page,unless you're going to dynamically include content with php which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And even if you include your static `.js` and `.css` etc. in the HTML, it's still downloaded by the user and he can extract it from the page source.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because a "direct" request is exactly the same as a request made in pursuit of a static asset.  Whatever you're trying to achieve, it's almost certainly wrong and misguided, but at the very least you'll want to describe what you're trying to achieve, not ask how to implement whatever solution you've already come up with, because it's just plain wrong.

Comment: How do I redirect anyone who goes to `mysite.com/js/*` back to `mysite.com/`?  Would that involve mod_rewrite?

Comment: Put questions in questions, not comments.